# SQL getting rows that match my condition

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL table that has the following :

```
+---------------------+
| id | mode   | value |
+---------------------+
|  1 | EXCLUDE |  10  |
|  2 | INCLUDE |  10  |
|  3 | EXCLUDE |  10  |
|  3 | EXCLUDE |  20  |
+---------------------+
```

So imagine these are products. Product 1, has all values but 10. Product 2 has value 10 only. Product 3 has all values but 10 and 20.

I need an sql that given a value, I should return all products that this value is valid.

e.g. a value of 10 should return product 2. a value of 30 should return product 1 and 3.

Tried this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE  ( mode = 'INCLUDE' AND value IN( 10) ) OR 
       ( mode = 'EXCLUDE' AND value NOT IN ( 10 ) )
```

for value 10 for example, but it also return the 4th row, which is expected based on the sql. How can i fix it? I want to group somehow the exclude ones based on the id and check values inside that ?

Comment: @StefanoZanini correct, was a typo. value of 30 should return 1 and 3.

Comment: where is 30 coming from? what are all values you are referring to?

Comment: @vkp they can be any value, no restriction. so exclude means any value other than the ones mentioned.

Comment: Is there a list of all possible values somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id
FROM
    products p
WHERE
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE id = p.id AND value = 10 AND mode = 'INCLUDE' )
    OR 
    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE id = p.id AND value = 10 AND mode = 'EXCLUDE')
```

Comment: This returns `1,2,3` instead of `1,3` when `value = 30`

Answer (score 3):

Using `not exists()`

```
select distinct p.id
from products p
where (mode = 'INCLUDE' and value in (30))
  or (
    not exists (
      select 1 
      from products i
      where i.id = p.id 
        and mode = 'EXCLUDE' 
        and value in (30)
      )
    and exists (
      select 1 
      from products i
      where i.id = p.id 
        and mode = 'EXCLUDE' 
        and value not in (30)
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `id`s are on multiple lines.  So, think `group by`, with the conditions in `having`:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN mode = 'INCLUDE' and VALUE IN (10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR
       (SUM(CASE WHEN mode = 'EXCLUDE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND -- has excludes 
        SUM(CASE WHEN mode = 'EXCLUDE' and VALUE IN (10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 -- but not this one
       );
```

This is complicated logic.  I think the logic is:

- Keep the id if any `id` explicitly includes the value.
- Remove the id if any `id` explicitly excludes the value.
- Keep the id if any row excludes other values, but not this value.

Comment: if this is to be used in a language like c++, would you just return the products and do any logic on the top layer? (inside the function that calls my db wrapper ). Would it be faster?

Comment: @ghostrider . . . In general, doing logic in the database is faster.  To do logic in the application requires returning unnecessary rows to the app for additional processing.